# how is __dirname implemented in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am quite new to Node.js and have come across the "__dirname" and found it to be quite handy for getting the absolute directory path of the script. But I am curious as to how it is implemented, how is it able to understand the directory structure. I have gone through the node js source code but I am not able to find a proper answer.

Comment: My guess would be something similar to `require("path").dirname(__filename)`

Comment: interesting.. another global variable.. I wonder where are all these coming from? Also, i tried to print out the value of __filename in a test script, it gave me the absolute path of the file. So my next question would be.. how is __filename implemented?

Comment: Probably start [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6ca5ea38602c07260bf422b0ae97f7f8160e661a/src/node.js#L965-L980).

Answer (score 1):

these object are available globally to use in node
   create a file anywhere in your system with any name suppose app.js
    and write in that file

```
 console.log(__dirname);
```

run it like :-

```
    node app.js
```

it will print the path of current directory.

Comment: Yes, I understand that they are available globally. but then how is it implemented in way that they behave in such a way?

Comment: arvind please clarify your statement clearly, i mean if this is printing the current directory path in your code then what else you want to do ,i mean what is your requirement

Comment: He wants the code behind __dirname in the Node source.

Comment: I want the internal implementation of __dirname, how is it able to give the directory value dynamically, how is this global populated? Say for example __dirname = getDirName(), where getDirName is a function which populates it, how is this function implemented? hope it makes sense.

Comment: look in your basic file create a variable global.__basePath = __dirname  and use it in your application to define the path dynamically like __basePath/your file name .

Comment: mayank, I believe you have not understood my question properly. I agree with @AdrianLynch, I want the code behind __dirname in the Node source

Comment: okay @arvind you can use it like :- var path = require('path');

  path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/file')  //for the relative path of your script.

Comment: He knows how to use it, he is interested in the implementation of it in Node, C++ most likely.